# Putting all table names that a KQL query uses into a List in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

Let's say I have a KQL query that uses several tables to retrieve the data.
I need to write some code in C#, that will take all the tables used by a given KQL query, and put all those table names into a list.

Simply put: I need to analyze each KQL query to know from which tables it gets the data.

I already tried doing so by writing this code:

```
var query = "Table1 | project a ,b,c";
       var code = KustoCode.Parse(query);‏
var parseCode = code.Analyze();
Console.WriteLine(parseCode.ResultType.Display.ToString());
```

But this doesn't return the **tables** names, but instead it returns the **columns** names that this query used, which is not what I want.

If you could help me solve this I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the help! I finally was able to find a solution for this so here is my code:

```
var code = KustoCode.Parse(query).Analyze();

SyntaxElement.WalkNodes(code.Syntax,
       Operator =>
       {
           if (Operator is Expression e && e.RawResultType is TableSymbol && Operator.Kind.ToString() == "NameReference")
               tables.Add(e.RawResult.Name);
       })
```

Note that very simple query expressions such as "mytable" will not be interpreted correctly since they are inherently ambiguous.

Comment: Check out: https://github.com/microsoft/Kusto-Query-Language

Answer (score 1):

This would seem to do the trick (based on `.show queryplan`)

```
using System.Data;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

string query = @".show queryplan <| search in (database('*').*) * | summarize count() by $table";
string cluster = "https://help.kusto.windows.net/Samples";

using (var client = Kusto.Data.Net.Client.KustoClientFactory.CreateCslQueryProvider($"{cluster};Fed=true"))
{
    using IDataReader reader = client.ExecuteQuery(query);

    reader.Read();
    reader.Read();
    string relop_tree = reader.GetString(2);
    JObject content = JObject.Parse(relop_tree);

    IEnumerable<JToken> sources = content.SelectTokens("$.source.operands..[?(@.source.type == 'TableShardReference')].source");

    foreach (JToken source in sources)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{source.Value<string>("database"), -50}{source.Value<string>("table")}");
    }
}
```

---

```
ContosoSales                                      SalesFact
ContosoSales                                      Products
ContosoSales                                      Customers
ContosoSales                                      SalesTable
KustoMonitoringPersistentDatabase                 KustoMonitoringTable
SampleIoTData                                     RawSensorsData
SampleIoTData                                     TransformedSensorsData
SampleIoTData                                     _MV_LatestSensorValue
SampleLogs                                        RawSysLogs
SampleLogs                                        TransformedSysLogs
SampleLogs                                        TraceLogs
SampleLogs                                        TargetTable
SampleMetrics                                     RawServerMetrics
SampleMetrics                                     TransformedServerMetrics
SampleMetrics                                     _MV_TransformedMetricsDedup
SampleMetrics                                     SQLServerLocation
SampleMetrics                                     _MV_AvgPerfWithServersHierarchy
Samples                                           StormEvents
Samples                                           demo_make_series1
Samples                                           demo_series2
Samples                                           demo_series3
Samples                                           demo_many_series1
Samples                                           ConferenceSessions
Samples                                           demo_make_series2
Samples                                           demo_clustering1
Samples                                           Covid19_Bing
Samples                                           Covid19_map2
Samples                                           US_States
Samples                                           US_Counties
Samples                                           irregular_ts
Samples                                           _MV_DailyCovid19
Samples                                           demo_prometheus
Samples                                           PopulationData
Samples                                           OccupancyDetection
Samples                                           SamplePowerRequirementHistorizedData
```

Comment: Deleting this answer. Unfortunately, it seems to be relevant only to very specific kind of queries.

Comment: Please un un-accept this answer so I could delete it. Thanks

Comment: It might be useful to keep up for future reference, but just edit the beginning to warn that it only works for said specific kinds of queries.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is knowable a priori as some table names can be resolved at query time and some queries (for example using find) can cover all/multiple tables that are not enumerated until query time.

You can find this information shortly after the fact if you turn on Table Usage Statistics in the 'Diagnostic settings' tab in the azure portal view of your ADX cluster. This will pump detailed information into an app insights resource that will show what table/extents get used.