# Putting all table names that a KQL query uses into a List in Python

Tags: python, azure-data-explorer, kql

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73322172/putting-all-table-names-that-a-kql-query-uses-into-a-list-in-c-sharp) and I was wondering whether there was an equivalent response (or package) for Python?
I've searched and it turns out that the Nuget package is capable of building a NPM package, but the NPM package isn't working well and lacks severely in documentation.

In short, I'm provided a query in KQL, and want to be able to list the concerned tables (and even columns if possible). I could parse it the old way but if it's possible to avoid reinventing the wheel, I'd be very grateful.

TIA!

Comment: Could you provide some more information so the community will try to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Currently this capability only exists as a C# code. https://github.com/microsoft/Kusto-Query-Language

Please consider voting for it on https://aka.ms/adx.ideas